# pyacret predict_model() function throwing exception in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr, joblib, pycaret

I have been trying to predict a model using pycaret on aws lambda and its throwing this weird exception. It seems like its trying to write something in the lambda directory which is read only.

```
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 763, in _check_previous_func_code
self.store_backend.get_cached_func_code([func_id]))
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_store_backends.py", line 284, in get_cached_func_code
with self._open_item(filename, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/gj/4q4s5q4s64x5jgq07g83rdcc0000gn/T/joblib/pycaret/internal/pipeline/_full_transform/func_code.py'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 39, in lambda_handler
prediction = predict_model(trained_model, raw_score = True, data = df)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/classification/functional.py", line 2201, in predict_model
return experiment.predict_model(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/classification/oop.py", line 2843, in predict_model
return super().predict_model(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/supervised_experiment.py", line 4952, in predict_model
X_test_ = pipeline.transform(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pipeline.py", line 271, in transform
X, y = self._memory_full_transform(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 655, in __call__
return self._cached_call(args, kwargs)[0]
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/internal/memory.py", line 350, in _cached_call
self._check_previous_func_code(stacklevel=4)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 765, in _check_previous_func_code
self._write_func_code(func_code, first_line)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 717, in _write_func_code
self.store_backend.store_cached_func_code([func_id], func_code)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_store_backends.py", line 272, in store_cached_func_code
self.create_location(func_path)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_store_backends.py", line 403, in create_location
mkdirp(location)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/disk.py", line 61, in mkdirp
os.makedirs(d)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[Previous line repeated 5 more times]
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/folders'
```

I tried to run the code in local docker container and it worked. It works on my local system as well. Not sure what else I could do.

Comment: Any reason this is tagged with `amazon-ecs` if you are running it on `aws-lambda`?

Comment: My bad!! It should be `amazon-ecr`.. I am using ecr to deploy